# Office 365 Excel crashes when copying worksheet to new workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I need to make reports by copying multiple worksheets to different files using Office 365 Business Excel. I can't use Office 2010 or 2013 because of organisation's policies.

Configuration:

- Windows 10
- MS Office 365 Business or Office 2016 (32bit/64bit)
- Excel file size 8-10 MB; format xlsx

When I try to copy worksheets Excel becomes inactive. It hangs about 20 min. and crashes or finally finishes his work.
It happens on Office 365 Business and Office 2016. When i tried the same action on Office 2013 or 2010 the job was done after 20 sec. and no hangs or crashes.

What i have tried:

1. Office 365 Business (32bit/64bit) - not working
2. Office 2016 (32bit/64bit) - not working
3. Office 2010/2013 - works fine
4. Repair Office programs
5. Installed all Windows and Office updates
6. Tried to run excel in safe mode
7. Tried to disable add-ins
8. Tried to disable hardware graphics acceleration

Any sugessions?

Comment: are there any macros in the workbooks?

Comment: There is no macros

Comment: have you tried on different computer running 2016/365?  if its a company computer with 2016/365, have your tried a non company computer with 2016/365?

Comment: Yes I have tried and got the same result

Comment: Are you doing this manually?

Comment: At this moment it is done manually. We get xlsx document form third party and then we make few different files. It contains data and graphs. Copies to different files are done by selecting group of workshets and using Move or copy option.

Comment: Did you try to run as an administrator?